# how to add caption and link to image gallery modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simplemodal

I am trying to customize a html template. 
which is

https://html5up.net/ethereal

it has a gallery with modal.
i want to add a simple link and some text in that modal.
but i am unable to do so.

can any one please help me.

Thank You

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: can you provide an screenshot how you want to show?

Comment: here is the html and js
https://gist.github.com/ehsanatwork/21551df982dfb2d35cd1797c7a8f5f4b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps :
each gallery image add caption and link data like this :

```
<a href="images/gallery/fulls/01.jpg" class="image filtered span-3" data-position="bottom" data-url="addlink" data-caption="addcaption"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

in the main.js find this line

```
$modalImg = $modal.find('img'),
href = $a.attr('href');
```

and below this add these line:

```
var caption = $a.data('caption');
var capurl = $a.data('url');
$modal.find('.caption').remove();
```

then find this line

```
$modalImg.attr('src', href);
```

and after this add(caption and link)

```
if(caption!=undefined){
$modalImg.before('<div class="caption"><a href="'+capurl+'">'+caption+'</a></div>');
}
```

Comment: WOW, amazing, thank you.

one more thing,
can i separate the caption and link.
i mean caption will be text and link will be icon.

Thank you.

Comment: yes you can do this by changing this snippet :
if(caption!=undefined){
$modalImg.before('<div class="caption"><h3>'+caption+'</h3><a href="'+capurl+'">icon url</a></div>');
}